# Running ReportPortal in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I try to run ReportPortal in my minikube:

```
# Delete stuff from last try
minikube delete

minikube start --driver=docker

minikube addons enable ingress

helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/

mv v5 reportportal/

helm dependency update

helm install . --generate-name

→ Error: failed pre-install: warning: Hook pre-install reportportal/templates/migrations-job.yaml failed: Job.batch "chart-1601647169-reportportal-migrations" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[4].valueFrom.secretKeyRef.name: Invalid value: "": a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')
```

Here is the file harts.yaml: https://github.com/reportportal/kubernetes/tree/master/reportportal/v5

What could be wrong?

Comment: I checked [here](https://github.com/reportportal/kubernetes/blob/master/reportportal/v5/templates/migrations-job.yaml#L37-L40) and it points to postgresql secret name in [values.yaml](https://github.com/reportportal/kubernetes/blob/master/reportportal/v5/values.yaml#L133). Could you try to change that from `""` to `your postgresql secret name` and try install it again? You can change it in your values.yaml or with [--set](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/reportportal/kubernetes/tree/master/reportportal/v5)

> Before you deploy ReportPortal you should have installed all its requirements. Their versions are described in [requirements.yaml](https://github.com/reportportal/kubernetes/blob/master/reportportal/v5/requirements.yaml)
> You should also specify correct PostgreSQL and RabbitMQ addresses and ports in [values.yaml](https://github.com/reportportal/kubernetes/blob/master/reportportal/v5/values.yaml)

```
rabbitmq:
  SecretName: ""
  installdep:
    enable: false
  endpoint:
    address: <rabbitmq_chart_name>-rabbitmq-ha.default.svc.cluster.local
    port: 5672
    user: rabbitmq
    apiport: 15672
    apiuser: rabbitmq

postgresql:
  SecretName: ""
  installdep:
    enable: false
  endpoint:
    cloudservice: false
    address: <postgresql_chart_name>-postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local
    port: 5432
    user: rpuser
    dbName: reportportal
    password:
```

---

I checked [here](https://github.com/reportportal/kubernetes/blob/master/reportportal/v5/templates/migrations-job.yaml#L37-L40) and it points to postgresql secret name in [values.yaml](https://github.com/reportportal/kubernetes/blob/master/reportportal/v5/values.yaml#L133).

The solution here would be to change that from `""` to your `postgresql secret name` and install it again. You can change it in your values.yaml or with [--set](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/), which specify overrides on the command line